# How to display saved Custom field value with reviews for product details page in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, products, review, product-review

I have created Custom fields in admin section for "catalog_product_review" comment reviews reply. i have created reply field for every comment, from admin side admin can reply to products comment. i have saved reply field value in database table "review_detail".

Now I want display Reply for every comment to customers on front end.
How to do. Is there any custom code please give me suggestion or share custom code.
because I'm unable to find the custom code for display reply for every comment like on reviews section on products detail page.

Comment: I have created reply field for every customer comment for like we need to go  
Catalog-> Review and rating->Customer Reviews-> All Reviews
From all reviews when we edit single review then below of Review textarea field I have created Reply custom field and saved reply field data using override 
/www/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php  in review_detail table in database
it is working with extra field reply for review. Now I want display reply for review on product details page
/www/app/design/frontend/default/Mytheme/template/review/product/view/list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed issue for showing extra custom fields value from review_detail database table to product detail page.

**I have overide file called Collection.php from core file to my local like
copy file from
/www/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review/Collection.php
to
/www/app/code/local/Mage/Review/Model/Resource/Review/Collection.php
and edit function from Collection.php**

**protected function _initSelect()
{  parent::_initSelect();
$this->getSelect()
->join(array('detail' => $this->_reviewDetailTable),
'main_table.review_id = detail.review_id',
array('detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'reply', 'nickname', 'customer_id'));
return $this;
}**

I have added my fields on above function fields liuke reply.It is working fine.